# Como puedo agrupar registros con mismo id

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia, todavia estoy aprendiendo y queria ver si me pueden apoyar para darle alguna solucion al problema siguiente,

me gustaria saber como puedo agrupar los registros de los mismos id, por ejemplo en la imagen 1 hay dos registros con el id 13 me gustaria que se agruparan esos registros en un mismo id y que no salgan separados, de igual manera con el id 16.

[image: Imagen 1]

Tengo 3 Tablas

**MRB** el id de esta tabla se liga con un campo identificador en la tabla
**Serial1** y esta tabla se liga el campo identificador con el campo identificador de la tabla
**defectos**

```
SELECT
       mrb.id,mrb.Fecha1,mrb.Nombre,mrb.Ayuda,mrb.Contenedor,mrb.Criticas,mrb.Condicion,mrb.Quejas,mrb.Wi,mrb.Motivo,mrb.fecha2,mrb.Numerointerno,serial1.serial1 as Serial1,mrb.Orden,mrb.Cliente,mrb.Total,mrb.Comentarios,
        
    sum(CASE WHEN defectos.Defecto = 'Tiro corto' THEN defectos.Cantidad ELSE 0 END)AS Tiro,
    SUM(CASE WHEN defectos.Defecto = 'Rebaba' THEN defectos.Cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS Rebaba,
      


       FROM mrb

       inner JOIN serial1
        ON mrb.id = serial1.identificador 
        inner join defectos on serial1.serial1 = defectos.identificador2
     

        
        where mrb.Fecha3 BETWEEN '$fechaInit' AND '$fechaFin'
       
       GROUP By serial1.serial1
```

Intente que se agruparan con GROUP_CONCAT pero me duplica los registros como se muestra en la imagen 2

[image: imagen 2]

```
SELECT
       mrb.id,mrb.Fecha1,mrb.Nombre,mrb.Ayuda,mrb.Contenedor,mrb.Criticas,mrb.Condicion,mrb.Quejas,mrb.Wi,mrb.Motivo,mrb.fecha2,mrb.Numerointerno,GROUP_CONCAT(serial1.serial1 SEPARATOR '<br>' ) as Serial1,mrb.Orden,mrb.Cliente,mrb.Total,mrb.Comentarios,
        
    sum(CASE WHEN defectos.Defecto = 'Tiro corto' THEN defectos.Cantidad ELSE 0 END)AS Tiro,
    SUM(CASE WHEN defectos.Defecto = 'Rebaba' THEN defectos.Cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS Rebaba,



       FROM mrb

       left JOIN serial1
        ON mrb.id = serial1.identificador 
        left join defectos on serial1.identificador = defectos.identificador
     

        
        where  serial1.serial1 = defectos.identificador2 and mrb.Fecha3 BETWEEN '$fechaInit' AND '$fechaFin'
       
       GROUP By id
```

en la tabla

serial1 guardo seriales registrados con el identificador correspondiente, todos los seriales con mismo identificador deben de estar agrupados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la tabla defectos, guardo los defectos de cada serial, y los defectos los relaciono con el serial que corresponde ese defecto, y tengo el identificador dos para saber a que grupo pertenece ese serial. (Ignoren los que no tienen serial, estaba realizando pruebas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces me gustaria que los registros salieran de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda y  disculpen si no me llegue a explicar bien

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13FUh4QaU456iKl7xOG1LMD-CUd4liFhl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Veo dos opciones: 1) No agrupes en SQL sino en PHP, o 2) Haz dos consultas, agrupa la primera por id y úsalo para obtener en la segunda los seriales (sin agrupar).

Comment: Hola primero que nada gracias por tu respuesta, Crees que me puedas apoyar con la opcion 2 con un ejemplo ?  Muchas Gracias Sal

Comment: Por lo que comentas y el resultado que esperas, no necesitas agrupar, sino ordenar e ir haciendo subtotales. Edita la pregunta añadiendo el dataset en SQL (desde phpmyadmin, exportar) y te ayudamos a montarlo